# Buffer cannot be null

Tags: vb.net, gridview, download

I try to download files from gridview ..  I save files in database and then I display in grid-view I try this

I save files in database table not in folder so I try to download files

when i do this document is download but there is problem when  i debug the code and check  then in this line 
 Dim row = db_stu.dResult.Tables(0).Rows(i)
dResult shows

```
   docid     document       docname     docextension
    1014    System.Byte[]   Book2.xlsx  .xlsx
```

and then when i further proceed docname shows "1912218726836.xlsx" this and also file download as a corrupt

Comment: Please don't start demanding help moments after posting your question.  We'll get to it if and when we can.  We are all volunteers who are scattered across the world, in different time zones.  Noone will help because of that pointless comment who wasn't already going to help.

Comment: Look at the title of this question.  Is that issue addressed?  If so, either accept the answer that addressed it or add an answer of your own.  If you have a different question then post it in a new thread.

Comment: okkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines together are wrong:

```
Dim binary() As Byte = TryCast(structDb.dstResult.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("document"), Byte())
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(binary)
```

The reason to use TryCast is that the object that you're trying to cast may not be the type you're trying to cast it as.  In that case, `TryCast` will return `Nothing`.  Use of `TryCast` should ALWAYS be followed by a test for `Nothing`, which you haven't done.  You're using the result as though you're sure that there will be an object of that type.  If you know that then you should be using `DirectCast` rather than `TryCast`.

Even if you do know that the reference will not be to an object of a different type and you use `DirectCast` though, if you cast a null reference, i.e. `Nothing`, then you're still going to get `Nothing` back.  So, you first need to determine whether `structDb.dstResult.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("document")` can refer to an object of a type other than `Byte()`.  If it can't then use `DirectCast` rather than `TryCast`.  Either way, it appears that that expression can produce `Nothing` so you need to check for `Nothing` either way, e.g.

```
Dim binary() As Byte = TryCast(structDb.dstResult.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("document"), Byte())

If binary IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(binary)

    '...
End If
```

EDIT: If the column is nullable then you need to first test whether the row contains null and then only use the data if there is some:

```
Dim row = structDb.dstResult.Tables(0).Rows(i)

If Not row.IsNull("document") Then
    'There is data so go ahead and use it.
    Dim binary = DirectCast(row("document"), Byte())

    '...
```

Comment: when i use direct cast this shows an error Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Comment: So what exactly did you expect to happen using `TryCast`?  Did you think that that `DBNull` would magically become a `Byte()`?  You obviously have a nullable column and some rows contain null in that column.  What exactly do you expect to happen when there's no data to use?  If there's no data, don't try to use data.  Also, why didn't you provide that information in the first place?  It would have saved some wasted time.  I'll update my answer with a more appropriate code snippet.

Comment: I tried your answer check updated question please @jmcilhinney